# Typescript: Specify multiple possible values for a key in an interface

Tags: typescript

How can I express `warningMessage` is only allowed to hold a value of online or offline?

````
      interface DataInterface {
        shared?: {
            bio?: string;
            country?: string;
            dob?: Date;
            email?: string;
            fullName?: string;
            gender?: string;
            username?: string;
            warningMessage?: string; // <== How can I express this can only hold a value of online or offline?
            webSite?: string;
        };
      }
      const data: DataInterface = {};
      if (true) data.shared.warningMessage = 'Online';
      if (true) data.shared.warningMessage = 'Offline';
      if (true) data.shared.warningMessage = "This should fail as its not 'Online' or 'Offline'";
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union of string literal types:

```
interface DataInterface {
  shared: {
    bio?: string;
    country?: string;
    dob?: Date;
    email?: string;
    fullName?: string;
    gender?: string;
    username?: string;
    warningMessage?: "Online" | "Offline"; // <== How can I express this can only hold a value of online or offline?
    webSite?: string;
  };
}
const data: DataInterface = {
  shared: {}
};
data.shared.warningMessage = 'Online';
data.shared.warningMessage = 'Offline';
//Err
data.shared.warningMessage = "This should fail as its not 'Online' or 'Offline'";
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAkua8nIDeAsAFDLIDOAFnFBACYBcRZFFARsAPYD8LlMFFABzANxt2CbgFdwUAJ78qQ0RPLsG3DsvSR17ZBAC2cYABtlg4SHGSKMGefMA5OMYhXVtg+xEQQBmgvGzsNChlKaBB3TwFvMMMAdzoQUQBZCEpKOH9lACIAeRBzUAh85AAfZCKYGFKQcrFkAHoW5AAeAF4u5AAJbiTkBDgQZCwjAA8AB3ps5DBqYEph0eRuEoVkam5zBmQ4ZAA3OHMZFG4YdZKy9ah1uobPe2QkiA4AZWBIELVJAF91P8yNIQIJkAwMHAWHpsLhYIgUL0SBoaHRGCxCMDSICyJDMAA6NH0BgElJQNK2TLZXJI5AAcmKT3p6nxcCJtBJZNSGSyOX8yF6jMeZRZeKhHPRpPJlJE1P5dPyABUlisaLI9sh4BYDitvisQNwwAymaK7iaRY16fl1EA)